# Compute the product of an increasing number of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, product, matrix-multiplication

I have a constant integer `m`, with a known value. We define a matrix called `M` whose elements are as follows:

```
      | M_11  M_12 |
M_i ≜ |            |
      | M_21  M_22 |
```

Initially, `m` 2x2 matrices are generated (i.e. `M1,...,M5`). Then, for every integer between `1` and `m`, I need to compute a matrix, such that

```
for m=1, P1 = M1
for m=2, P2 = M1.M2
for m=3, P3 = M1.M2.M3 
and so on
```

How do I extract `P_11` of the product matrices and plot it against `m`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's not entirely clear what you're asking, I'm providing two solutions within the same answer. For more information, please see the comments in the code below.

```matlab
function q59596709
%% Definitions:
rng(59596709); % for reproducibility
m = 5;
SZ = 2;

%% Preallocation
[P_arr,P_mat] = deal(zeros(m,1)); % preallocation

%% Generate data:
M = rand(SZ,SZ,m);

%% Perform ARRAY multiplication
for ind1 = 1:m
  tmp = prod(M(:,:,1:ind1),3);
  P_arr(ind1) = tmp(1); % get the first (i.e. 1,1) element
end

%% Perform MATRIX multiplication
tmp = eye(SZ);
for ind1 = 1:m
  tmp = tmp * M(:,:,ind1);
  P_mat(ind1) = tmp(1);  % get the first (i.e. 1,1) element
end

%% Show the first element:
figure(); plot(1:m, P_arr, 1:m, P_mat); 
xlabel('m'); ylabel('value'); set(gca, 'FontSize', 14);
legend('M_{11}, ARRAY multiplication', 'M_{11}, MATRIX multiplication');
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I need the matrix multiplication of every 2 by  2 matrix.

Comment: I understand that you have generated a array of 2 by 2 matrices using 4 random numbers as elements. But matrix elements M_11,M_12,M_21 and M_22 are also functions of m which changes with m. I need to know how to generate the array of M matrix with those known elements instead of M = rand(SZ,SZ,m); Instead of using rand function, how to achieve that.

Comment: The code I tried was, MM=[m11 m12;m21 m22];M=MM(:,:,m); This isn't working. It says that the index exceeds matrix dimensions. Your answer was really helpful. Thank you for that.

Comment: @D.R. Since we know the size of `M` in advance, we can do `M(:,:,m) = MM`.